# In java, how can you make a method that classifies an object based on previous methods?

Tags: java, methods, static

I'm working on a lab for AP Comp Sci that includes a vector class and and Quadrilateral class. The vector class constructs vectors and the quadrilateral class constructs a quadrilateral from 4 vectors, and then is supposed to classify the type of quadrilateral. To do this I'm testing for each individual shape it could be with code like

```
public boolean isParallelogram()
{
    if(side1.isParallel(side3) && side2.isParallel(side4))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then when it gets to the point to return a classification for the quadrilateral I'm unable to use these methods and what they return because "non static method __________ cannot be referenced in a static context". how can I classify it if I can't access these methods because that quadrilateral object does not exist always? This is my current classify method,

```
public static String classify()
{
    System.out.print("quadrilateral");
    return "quadrilateral";

    if(Quadrilateral.isParallelogram() == true)
    {
        System.out.print(" - parallelogram");
        return " - parallelogram";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass it a *specific* quadrilateral object to classify, and then it can call the methods on that object. Right now it's like your asking if a person is tall or short, but not any *specific* person, just people in general.

Comment: Also, `if (boolean expression) return true; else return false;` isn't very good style; you can replace it with `return boolean expression;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to invoke the method directly from the class, it shall be declared as `static`:

```
public static boolean isParallelogram()
```

---

**However**, if the method is not to be associated to the class, but to individual objects, you need  to instantiate the object first (In this case, your method ***does not need*** to be `static`).

```
Quadrilateral quad = new Quadrilateral();    //instantiate first
if(quad.isParallelogram()){
    //do whatever
}
```

To me `isParallelogram()` does not look like a class method anyway, so you may  choose 2nd opotion, i.e. instantiate the object first before invoking its method.

---

But if `classify` is a behaviour of class `Quadrilateral`. Then it shall look like:

```
//Assuming this method checks itself whether it is a quadtrilateral or parallelogram
public String classify()           //no static declaration
{
    if(this.isParallelogram()){    //apply the check on itself
        System.out.print("parallelogram");
        return "parallelogram";
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("quadrilateral");
        return "quadrilateral";
    }
}
```

Comment: if I put a static in the isParalleogram method, then I get the same issue as the classify method, just 1 level higher up. now the compiler tells me "non static variable side1 cannot be referenced in a static context". if I put static in the constructor, where side1 is initialized it says "modifier static not allowed here"

Comment: I don't suggest making it static, because that method doesn't look like it belong to the class. Just instantiate the object (**without** making the method`static`). It is in my solution.

Comment: the isParallelogram method and classify method are both in the class? also how can you instantiate the object first? You can't guarantee that there will always be an object created when the code is compiled.

Comment: @LiamGuthrie Is `classify()` a behaviour of `Quadrilateral` class? If it is, then it shall not be `static`. If it is just a method from the client class which for example, resides beside your main() method for testing the codes, then it shall be static.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by behavior, but classify is a method in Quadrilateral class. It isn't labeled as static but the compiler still refers to it as a "static context" or at least the line -  if(Quadrilateral.isParallelogram() == true)  -  as static context

Comment: If it is a method in Quadrilateral class, it **shall not be** `static`. Behaviours are like `run()`, `walk()`, `talk()` from a `Person` class for example. Those are behaviours of a Person and can be invoked from individual object.

Comment: oh thank you! -  this.isParallelogram -  is what I needed. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

`static` methods cannot be called by non-static methods. What I believe is that you have a class Vector. You can have class `Quadrilateral` something like:

```
public class Quadrilateral {
      private List<Vector> sides;

      public Quadrilateral(List<Vector> sides){
            this.sides = sides;
      }
      // Have non-static methods
      public classify() {}
      public isParallelogram() {}
}
```

Now you instantiate `Quadrilateral` and `Vector` class in some other class and use them like:

```
 Vector side1 = new Vector()
 Vector side2 = new Vector() // create two more vector objects
 Quadrilateral quadrilateral = new 
                Quadrilateral(Arrays.asList(side1,side2,side3,side4));
```

Then you can call `classify()` on this quadrilateral object. Hope this helps.